# Make an alias column from 2 different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, select

I have a database table which has correlation with 2 different tables, for example:

```
   === inventory ===
+------------+-----------+
|    code    |   total   |
+------------+-----------+
| el_pr_25   |     45    |
| el_pr_11   |     33    |
| mob_tp_x93 |     23    |
| mob_tp_t55 |     33    |
| el_pr_x73  |     25    |
| mob_tp_25  |     22    |
+------------+-----------+

= electricity =
+-----+-------+
|  id | name  |
+-----+-------+
|  25 | test1 |
|  11 | test2 |
| x73 | test3 |
+-----+-------+

  == mobile ==
+-----+----------+
|  id |   name   |
+-----+----------+
| x93 | test 66  |
| t55 | test 222 |
| 25  | test 323 |
+-----+----------+
```

the main table i want to select is the inventory table, the inventory table is connected to the other table through `code` column, for electricity table there is a `el_pr_` prefix followed by the `id` of the electricity table and for mobile table the prefix is `mob_tp_` is the prefix, i want to select the inventory table with the name column from the electricity and mobile table, for example the result will be like this:

```
SELECT code,total, ... as name FROM inventory; 


         === inventory ===
+------------+-----------+----------+
|    code    |   total   |  name    |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| el_pr_25   |     45    | test1    |
| el_pr_11   |     33    | test2    |
| mob_tp_x93 |     23    | test 66  |
| mob_tp_t55 |     33    | test 22  |
| el_pr_x73  |     25    | test3    |
| mob_tp_25  |     22    | test 323 |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: You are expected to try a query of your own, then if having difficulty with it, ask us to assist. What query have you attempted to use? (Please add it into the question, don't use a comment for this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try the following join query:

```
SELECT
    i.code,
    i.total,
    COALESCE(e.name, m.name) AS name
FROM inventory i
LEFT JOIN electricity e
    ON i.code REGEXP CONCAT('el_.*_', e.id, '$')
LEFT JOIN mobile m
    ON i.code REGEXP CONCAT('mob_.*', m.id, '$');
```

[image]

### Demo

The above query uses a `COALESCE` trick to choose the correct name for each item, which assumes that a given item would only match to either the `electricity` or `mobile` table.

But, your database design is not ideal.  It would be much better to just have a single table containing metadata for both mobile and electrical (and other) items.  In addtion, your tables should have proper join columns which *don't* require complex substring or regex operations to match.  I suggest the following:

```
inventory
+----+------------+-----------+
| id |    code    |   total   |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 1  | el_pr_25   |     45    |
| 2  | el_pr_11   |     33    |
| 3  | el_pr_x73  |     25    |
| 4  | mob_tp_x93 |     23    |
| 5  | mob_tp_t55 |     33    |
| 6  | mob_tp_25  |     22    |
+----+------------+-----------+

items
+--------------+----------+-------------+
| inventory_id | name     | type        |
+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 1            | test1    | electricity |
| 2            | test2    | electricity |
| 3            | test3    | electricity |
| 4            | test 66  | mobile      |
| 5            | test 222 | mobile      |
| 6            | test 323 | mobile      |
+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: and you are fine with this as a data model?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes, the database design is not ideal, and I'll add a comment about that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i know, i just receive the database from my higher up

Comment: @blue For your own information, as a suggestion, I gave a suggestion for how you might better structure your table data.  Just use numbers for the inventory keys, and don't create tables all over the place if you could just have a single logical table which does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

you may use `inner join` with `union [all]` as :

```
select i.*, e.name from inventory i 
                   inner join electricity e on ( i.code = concat('el_pr_',e.id) ) union all
select i.*, m.name from inventory i 
                   inner join mobile m on ( i.code = concat('mob_tp_',m.id) );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/RGT99958)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your data model into separate columns, and with a unique constraint formed by using them both.

```
|code  |   total   |type
+------+-----------+
| 25   |     45    |el_pr_
| 11   |     33    |el_pr_
| x93  |     23    |mob_tp_
| t55  |     33    |mob_tp_
| x73  |     25    |el_pr_
| 25   |     22    |mob_tp_
```

and combining the source of names into a single table

```
|  id | name  |type
+-----+-------+
|  25 | test1 |el_pr_
|  11 | test2 |el_pr_
| x73 | test3 |el_pr_
| x93 | test 66  |mob_tp_
| t55 | test 222 |mob_tp_
| 25  | test 323 |mob_tp_
```

then

```
select *
from inventory i
join tab_names n on i.type = n.type and i.code = n.id
```

This is just a rough outline!

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted +1.  Not a direct answer, but it's a good suggestion in any case.